# Netbeans "Generate Javadoc" throws error "package ... does not exist"

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

A Java 7 project in NetBeans 8.0 which compiles and runs fine is not able to generate Javadoc pages without throwing the error `Package packagename does not exist` in reference to a supporting package which is part of another project.

This happens even though the current project includes the supporting project as a library, which can be seen by right-clicking on the current project and selecting **Properties**, then selecting the **Libraries** category on the left, and checking that the supporting project is listed under the **Compile** tab as one of the "Compile-time Libraries".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NetBeans 8.0, with the current project open, go to the **Run** menu and then select **Clean and Build Project (ProjectName)** or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Once the project has been cleaned out and rebuilt, then go to the **Run** menu and select **Generate Javadoc (ProjectName)**. The generator should now be able to find the supporting project and the Javadoc pages should be generated without any errors about the existence of the required package.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this. It helped me.

1. Right Click on a package in your project
2. Go to tools, then
3. Select Analyse Javadoc.
4. Tick all the checkboxes and
5. Select fix selected.
   After you are done, do the same for the rest of the packages.

Now go ahead and run Generate javadoc.